# ionic cordova run browser --livereload cordova platform not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, browser, ionic3, livereload

I'm trying to run ionic cordova run browser --livereload on localhost:8100.

the platform cordova not working and if i run it on localhost:8000  the --livereload will not work

```
exports.ANDROID_PLATFORM_PATHS = [
    path.join('platforms', 'android', 'assets', 'www'),
    path.join('platforms', 'android', 'app', 'src', 'main', 'assets', 'www')
];
```

Comment: the correct flag is --live-reload

Comment: Is [ionic cordova run](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-run/) using mentioned `--livereload` what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **--livereload** flag is **not supported** when you run `ionic cordova run browser`.

More information here: [Issue 2312 - Ionic-team on github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2312)

If you don't need cordova emulation to test in your browser, you can use the following command that has default livereload support (but **no** cordova emulation):

`ionic serve`